# Inactive / Unknown TCP connections

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, tcpip, tcpdump

I can see the following TCP connections in one of my linux host.

```
root@odb-us:~# netstat -a | grep ESTAB  | grep 10.12
tcp        0      0 odb-us.:2424 10.12.0.77:40000        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 odb-us.:2424 10.12.0.77:39996        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 odb-us.:2424 10.12.0.77:39998        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 odb-us.:2424 10.12.0.77:37725        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 odb-us.:2424 10.12.0.77:39995        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 odb-us.:2424 10.12.0.77:39993        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 odb-us.:2424 10.12.0.77:40003        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 odb-us.:2424 10.12.0.77:39997        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 odb-us.:2424 10.12.1.10:50934        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 odb-us.:2424 10.12.0.77:40005        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 odb-us.:2424 10.12.0.77:40001        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 odb-us.:2424 10.12.0.80:45492        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 odb-us.:2424 10.12.0.77:39992        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 odb-us.:2424 10.12.0.77:40002        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 odb-us.:2424 10.12.1.9:56226         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 odb-us.:2424 10.12.0.77:40004        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 odb-us.:2424 10.12.0.77:39999        ESTABLISHED
```

I am not sure what those 10.12.x.x machines are. For past 2 days, I tried to do packet capture using tcpdump on that port grepping for the IP and on all traffic grepping for the IP. But I can't see any traffic. I also watched for all UDP traffic using tcpdump grepping for the IP. But there are no traffic on  to/from this IP address (10.12.x.x)

The following are my TCP settings.

```
root@odb-us:~# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time
7200
root@odb-us:~# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_intvl
75
root@odb-us:~# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_probes
9
```

Need help in troubleshooting this further.

Update : Adding 'netstat -r' output :

```
# netstat -r
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         10.230.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.230.0.1      *               255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eth0
```

Update 2:

```
# sudo netstat -lntp | grep 2424
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2424            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12801/java
```

Process 12801 is ODB database (java process)

```
# traceroute 10.12.0.77
traceroute to 10.12.0.77 (10.12.0.77), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
...TRUNCATED
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Comment: Post the output of `netstat -r`.

Comment: Updated in question.

Comment: So, whats running on port 2424? These are all incoming connections.

Comment: Post the output of `sudo netstat -lntp | grep 2424`

Comment: `10.*.*.*` are private local IPs. Your LAN also has an IP in this range (and no range, which is unusual) Are you directly connected to your ISP, and is this the IP range your ISP uses? Or are you connected to a router? What is the result of `mtr -t 10.12.0.77` or `traceroute 10.12.0.77`, compared to, say `mtr -t google.com`?

Comment: @DanielB: ODB database (java process) is running on that port.

Comment: @13nilux: Output updated in question

Comment: @dirkt : It is a vm in GCE (Google cloud). It is on private subnet 10.230.0.0. When I try to mtr to 10.12.0.77, it is showing blank screen (no hop). Traceroute output updated in question (still no next hop). mtr to google.com works fine as normal. (nothing related to 10.12).

Comment: Then it's probably something Google uses internally, behind some router which blocks you. And please don't use `netstat` for everything, `lsof -i:2424` or similar should give you better information, like the PID so you can look at the commandline.